# Power BI Distinct Count with a Filter

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Newbie to Power BI.

I created a This Year measure doing the following which works for Net Sales:

```
Net Sales TY = CALCULATE(SUM(Fact_Sales[Net Sales]),Dim_Date[Financial_CurrYearOffSet]=0)
```

I've tried to do the same with count distinct Transactions.

The original field is in the fact table and is text so I created a measure as numeric, this works.

```
Transaction Count = DISTINCTCOUNT(Fact_Sales[Distinct Transaction])
```

I then tried to filter the above doing this:

```
Transaction Count TY = CALCULATE(SUM(Fact_Sales[Transaction Count]),Dim_Date[Financial_CurrYearOffSet]=0)
```

The above doesn't let me create the measure so must be another way to perform this calculation when using count distinct, any ideas or pointers what to look for?

Thanks

Comment: Can you try just inputting "[Transaction Count]" instead of "SUM(Fact_Sales[Transaction Count]"?

Comment: Wow as simple as that, works perfectly many thanks Adrian

Comment: You are welcome. PowerBi can be frustrating at the beginning, keep it on!